# Conversión de texto a código morse.

Tags: java, array, string

gracias por leer, tengo un problema con un aplicacion con interfaz grafica en java, la cual convierte de texto a morse y de morse a texto, pero al oprimir el boto de texto a morse,no ocurre nada, no entiendo si el actionlistener usado esta mal codificado o son los metodos los cuales estan mal codificados, he revisado y la verdad no encuentro cual es el error.

A continuacion, el fragmento de codigo del action listener

```
public void actionPerformed2(ActionEvent f) {
    String palabra = interfaz.getTexto1();

    String conversion2 = convertidor.convertirTextoMorse(palabra);
    interfaz.settextoMorse(conversion2);

}

private void actionListener2(ActionListener f) {
    interfaz.btnTexto.addActionListener(f);

}
```

ahora el código del método que realiza la conversión de texto a morse.

```
public class Convertidor {

public String convertirTextoMorse(String palabra) {

    String morse[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", // a-i
            ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", // j-q
            ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".......", // r-" "
            ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", // A-G
            "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", // H-P
            "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", // Q-X
            "-.--", "--..", "......." }; // Y-Z

    String abecedario = (String) "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    int posicion = 0;
    String conversion = "";

    for (int f = 0; f < palabra.length(); f++) {
        posicion = abecedario.indexOf(palabra.charAt(f));
        conversion = conversion + morse[posicion] + " ";

    }
    return conversion;

}
```

El código consiste en recorrer la cadena obtenida a partir de un JTextfield y separandola, encontrarla en la posición de cada letra en la cadena abecedario, lo cual imprimiría lo contenido en la posición determinada de el arreglo morse.

Agradezco quien me de consejos y/o soluciones para solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que son tus listener. Me parece que debe ser asi:

```
btnTexto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String palabra = interfaz.getTexto1();

                String conversion2 = convertidor.convertirTextoMorse(palabra);
                interfaz.settextoMorse(conversion2);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda,tengo otro para el botón que realiza la conversión de morse a texto y funciona a la perfección, pero me gustaría saber porque puede ser el problema.

Comment: La Interface ActionListener trae consigo un método para registrar ese evento (clic en botón) el cual se llama 'actionPerformed' que entre otras cosas debe sobre-escribirse (override) para que funcione, si en vez de ese nombre se utiliza otro, como por ejemplo 'actionPerformed2' simplemente lo va a ignorar y no ocurrirá nada al hacer clic en el botón.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya pude solucionar el error!

Comment: Por favor, recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a las personas que me ayudaron, ya pude solucionar el problema , el cual era el ActionListener , lo moví a la interfaz y  cree nuevos métodos para poder usar la clase que realizaba la conversión, así quedo:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("convertir texto a morse")) {
        String palabra = txtLetra1.getText();
        String Conversion = convertidor.convertirTextoMorse(palabra);

        txtLetra2.setText(Conversion);

    }
```

Muchas gracias a todos!